# Sharing plugin tables between 2 sites in the same database

Tags: database

I would like to know how can I make my supportcandy plugin to read the database tables of another supportcandy plugin installed in another site, without activating the wordpress multisite feature.

I actually have 2 subdomains sharing the same database, but both with different database prefixes. Subdomain A has prefix abtf_ for its tables and subdomain B has prefix klmn_ for its tables. They both share the users, and the userdata, the keys, and cookies via the wp-config.php file. I made the needed changes in both configuration files and both wordpress installations work pretty fine. But my headeache comes when I try to make them share the plugin’s tables.

I want both installations of supportcandy to use the same database tables, and I don`t know really how to do it, I’ve been researching for days, I tried to do something similar as I did in the wp-config.php for linking both sites, but didn’t work, I tried by building an alternative wp-config.php just for supportcandy, and testing inside the plugin files to make it read the alternative wp-config.php, I tried to define custom constants inside wp-config…

I’m totally lost. If someone could give me a hand, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Normally wouldn't suggest sharing a database across two sites, doing so can and likely will cause issues. No one will suggest it, and even I would advise against it, but your best bet might be to edit the SupportCandy plugin files, there will likely be a database class making it much easier to swap out the prefix for just that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an alternative wp-config.php and renamed to wp-config2.php with the same configuration except for the table prefix.
Then I tried by editing all the plugin files. At the top of each file I found:

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {

```
exit; // Exit if accessed directly!
```

}

And I replaced it for:

require_once(ABSPATH . ‘wp-config2.php’);

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

But doesn't work. The plugin keeps connecting to the original tables instead of the tables I want it to connect to... I don't know what I've missing :S

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415921/edit) to include this information rather than posting it as an answer.